# Whats the best and fastest way to count the occurrences of text within all the cells in an Excel worksheet in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

What's the best and fastest way to Count the occurrences of text within all the cells in an Excel worksheet?
I want to be able to run a VBA method if I find a specific text within a cell in a sheet, and would run it if the count of text is > 0. I've tried to search online but there seem to be variations and not really sure what to use. what is the best way?

this was one code I tried but didnt work:

```
Sub Macro7()
'
If (WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A1:Z500"), "TTD")) > 0 Then
     Application.Run "PERSONAL.XLSB!TTDA"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Please add more context to this question. What type of worksheet are we talking about? What's the file format? Are you trying to accomplish this in a particular programming language or technology? Etc. Help us understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: I tagged Excel and VBA in the post didnt realize i needed to be more clear on that

Comment: @AlexGrounds - All your questions are answered. The OP needs to provide the code he has tried and an example of why its not working. If they can post the code and a picture or sample of the worksheet then we can help. Read [ask] for more.

Comment: I thought the question was fairly simple. im just trying to search a specific text and count how many times it occurs within an excel worksheet. the text could be within part of the text in a cell

Comment: I was wondering why the code I did in re-edit doesnt work and if Im doing anything wrong. also if there is a better way?

Comment: Change `"TTD"` to `"*TTD*"`.

Comment: @BigBen that still doesn't work

Comment: Fix your parentheses: `If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A1:Z500"), "*TTD*") > 0 Then`.

Comment: it skips over the Application run even though there is a cell that had TTD. the text though is in column A2 and is part of a few merged cells

Comment: Ok I guess minor details were causing me the issue. it works now!

Comment: @atgold18 - the question was fairly simple ... and do you see that after you added the code you tried how fast and simple the community was able to help you solve your issue :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add wildcards around the `TTD`.
2. Fix your parentheses. The closing outer parenthesis is in the wrong spot (should be *after* `>0`), but you can just drop the outer parentheses entirely.

```
If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A1:Z500"), "*TTD*") > 0 Then
```